# Restructure main menu markup

Tags: theming, routes

I need this structure to my drupal main-menu:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Cras justo odio
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

Im use bootstrap theme, and menu_block module.

this is my template.php file, I need to remove the li tags.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * template.php
 */

function bootstrap_subtheme_menu_tree__menu_block__main_menu($variables){
    //add class for ul
    return '<div class="list-group">' . $variables['tree'] . '</div>';
}
function bootstrap_subtheme_menu_link__menu_block__main_menu($variables){
    //add class for li
    //$variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = '';
    //add class for a
    $variables['element']['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'list-group-item';
    //dvm($variables['element']);
    return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Using theme overrides.**

You can override [theme_menu_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) and [theme_menu_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7) in your theme.

However, you probably only want to target this one menu and not every other menu. To achieve this, you can use [targeted overrides for theme_menu_link() and theme_menu_tree()](https://drupal.org/node/254940#theme-suggestions-for-menus):

```
THEMENAME_menu_tree__MENU_NAME()
THEMENAME_menu_link__MENU_NAME()
```

Or (as you figured out yourself) there are specific overrides for menu_block:

```
THEMENAME_menu_tree__menu_block__MENU_NAME()
THEMENAME_menu_link__menu_block__MENU_NAME()
```

Detail:

```
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__menu_block__MENU_NAME($variables){
    //add class for ul
    return '<div class="list-group">' . $variables['tree'] . '</div>';
}

function THEMENAME_menu_link__menu_block__MENU_NAME(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  // Omit all the submenu stuff, since this will only be used to display the top level.
  /*
    $sub_menu = '';

    if ($element['#below']) {
      $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }
  */
  $link_options = $element['#localized_options'];
  $link_options['attributes']['class'][] = 'list-group-item';
  return l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $link_options);
}
```

Comment: I am not a developer, I'm a designer learning to develop, thanks for the reply, but I need more help

Comment: Ok, but there is a limit to how much can be done in a stackexchange answer.
I assume you are using a custom theme that is a sub-theme of bootstrap?

Comment: "return theme_menu_link($variables);" this does not help, instead you should copy and modify the contents of theme_menu_link().

Comment: I use a sub-theme of bootstrap and menu_block module. I need to rewrite the markup of the menu show with the module menu_block

Comment: Answer modified.

Answer (score 2):

**2. With Menupoly (advanced users)**

An alternative solution is to use [Menupoly](http://drupal.org/project/menupoly) with a MenuTheme implementation that will render links without the ul/li. You can think of this like a formatter for menus.

**When and why?**

Typically, the basic theme overrides as in the other answer are sufficient.
But there are some use cases where Menupoly can be preferable:

- You want to reuse the theme html in another project, or for another menu.
- You want to render the same menu more than one place, with different HTML. E.g. in the header you want only links + separator, but in the sidebar you want the usual ul + li. In this case, the targeted theme override won't cut it.

**Solution 1: Menupoly as a block**

Create a custom module.

Optionally, create a custom MenuTheme implementation, similar to [this one](http://drupalcode.org/project/menupoly.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/lib/MenuTheme/FlatLinksWithSeparator.php). Or just use the existing one.

If you create your own, make sure that the class can be found with an autoloader, or put it in a file that is always included.

Then, implement hook_menupoly() to define a menu block:

```
function MYMODULE_menupoly() {
  return array(
    'topnav_flat' => array(
      'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
      'depth' => 1,
      'menu_theme' => new menupoly_MenuTheme_FlatLinksWithSeparator(' | '),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Solution 2: Without a block.**

To skip the part with the block, you can directly do this in your theme.

Implement `THEMENAME_preprocess_page()`, and add this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $settings = array(
    'expand' => MENUPOLY_EXPAND_ALL,
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
    ... // more options possible
  );
  $html = menupoly_view($settings);
  $vars['topnav_flat'] = menupoly_view($settings);
}
```

Then, in your `page.tpl.php`:

```
..
<?php print $topnav_flat; ?>
..
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I would like to resolve it with theme overrides, so it's like I've been doing all my projects.

thanks

Comment: This is fine. But the idea is that these questions and answers should be useful to other people, too..